# PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am currently trying to use the insert in a procedure but getting and error  table does not exist 
any idea why are we getting this i have provided the schema name and all.    here is my insert statment

```
INSERT INTO  
           fseries_cash.superduty_fast_cash_proc@wdev (
    seq_no,
    dealer_code,
    region_code,
    vin,
    claim_amt,
    claim_date,
    claim_status,
    program_code,
    sale_date,
    model_year,
    elim_flag,
    load_date,
    goldd_region
)
SELECT 
    seq_no
    --webcni.cni_c7_adhoc_records_seq.nextval, 
    dealer_code,  
    region_code,     
    vin,  
    claim_amt,     
    claim_date,     
    claim_status, 
    '20602',  
     sale_date,    
     model_year,    
     NULL, 
     sysdate,       
     NULL  
  FROM webcni.cni_c7_adhoc_records;
```

Comment: Well, this might be a little simplistic, but at a guess I'd say the table or view you're using in your query doesn't exist. Have you got the right name?

Comment: Does it work when you run it outside of the stored procedure?

Comment: And which table, the one you're selecting from or the one you're inserting into? And `fseries_cash.superduty_fast_cash_proc` sounds more like a package procedure name than a table. You aren't trying to call a remote procedure with values obtained from a query, are you?

Comment: Or it may be that the user utilized by the `wdev` link may not have INSERT privileges on `fseries_cash.superduty_fast_cash_proc` on the remote database. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using the table name as "fseries_cash.superduty_fast_cash_proc@wdev".

Looks like you are using database links here.

So make sure you do the below checks.

1. Check if the table name exists under the schema you specified. You can check using describe (desc).
2. Make sure that you got the mapping right...I mean your table indeed resides on the database server where the link wdev is pointing to...see if "desc fseries_cash.superduty_fast_cash_proc@wdev" gives any valid output.

If both the above points are fine, then you should not get an error.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks everyone . its was a grant issue . but werid one . when i try to do the simple insert  i was able to without any issue . but when i try to do it in the procedure was gettting ans error. but when i did the grant on the table i am wass .